# Why does Java never reach the end of this if/else?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, unreachable-code

I've been scratching my head at this for hours now, but I can't seem to figure this one out.
I'm writing a program that has a constant loop going in a Thread, which occasionally sends back data to another part of the program using an Arraylist.

I only want to send this data back after I have gathered 11 items in my arraylist. So I used this code:

```
//The rest of the loop in which i gather the values for key and velocity.

    notenbuffer.add(new Noot(key,velocity));
    if (notenbuffer.size() > 10){
    System.out.println("Notenbuffer > 10, verstuur data");
        
    if (notenbuffer.isEmpty()){
          System.out.println("buffer is empty!");

    }
    else {
          usbRead.writeNotes(notenbuffer);
          System.out.println("emptied the buffer!");
          notenbuffer.clear();
    }
        
    }
```

Now for some weird reason the program never empties the Arraylist, and just keeps on adding items to it. I've checked and it does in fact reach the `usbRead.writeNotes(notenbuffer)` part because this function gets called correctly. When I use the debugger it simply skips to the beginning of the loop after this function was called.

Is there a way in which I can empty an Arraylist once it reaches a certain size?

Edit: I made a logic error by writing `if (notenbuffer.isEmpty())` this will always be false because I am already in an if statement which requires this to be false.

Comment: Did you put your second if inside your first by accident? (The missing indentation seems to suggest so). Having `if (notenbuffer.isEmpty())` inside the `if (notenbuffer.size() > 10)` block makes no sense at all logically. After all if your List size is > 10 then the list is obviously not empty. So `if (notenbuffer.isEmpty())` can never be true at all.

Comment: You are checking the size is greater than 10 then if it is empty. There's a logic error here

Comment: I indeed made that logic error. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Is `notebuffer` used by more than one thread?  It might be cleared but then immediately filled by a different thread.

Comment: Are you ever adding more than 10 items to ``notenbuffer``?

Answer (score 0):

> Did you put your second if inside your first by accident? (The missing indentation seems to suggest so). Having if
> (notenbuffer.isEmpty()) inside the if (notenbuffer.size() > 10) block
> makes no sense at all logically. After all if your List size is > 10
> then the list is obviously not empty. So if (notenbuffer.isEmpty())
> can never be true at all. – OH GOD SPIDERS 15 mins ago

This was indeed the problem. Removing this exposed an NoClassDefFoundError that needed resolving.